# Time complexity analysis for recurrence relation

Tags: recursion, algorithm-analysis, big-o

I was asked to figure out the time complexity analysis for the following recurrence relation
`T(n) = 4*T(n-1) + c`.

Basically, I did a replacement.. `T(n-1) = 4 * T(n-2) + c` and so on..

```
T(n) = 4^k T(1) + c(1 + 4 + 4^2..4^(k-1))
```

I worked it out as O(4^k) Would like to know if this is right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`O(4^n)` seems to be correct as `c(1 + 4 + 4^2 + .. + 4^(n-1))` gives `c(4^n - 1) / 3` thus reducing it to `O(4^n)` and the first part is already `O(4^n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

The homogenous version of your recurrence relation is simply `T(n) = 5*T(n-1) - 4*T(n-2)` (You can get this by expressing `c` in the formula for `T(n)` and in the formula for `T(n-1)` and then equating them).

The characteristic polynomial of the relation is then `x^2 - 5x + 4 = 0`. Solving this you get the roots `1` and `4`. Hence any solution of the recurrence relation has form `a * 4^n + b * 1^n`, which simplifies to `a * 4^n + b`. The values of `a` and `b` depend on your initial conditions (the value of `c` and `T(0)`). For example, for `c = 1` and `T(1) = 1`, the solution is `1/3 * 4^n - 1/3` - you can check this yourself!

The overall strategy of solving these simple types of recurrence relations is described in the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).